# Will someone be punished again after death after once being already punished on the earth?

Tags: karma, sin

If someone did papa karma and got punishment for his karma on the earth. May be jailed for entire life,  or death punishment or any type of punishment, then will he be again punished for that?

Comment: No. Anyone who has suffered punishment for their crime at the hand of the government (rAja danDana) will not suffer punishment for the same crime in the afterlife.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**, A person can't get punishment of same sin twice. After getting punishment of his sin, person becomes sinless. If a King punish a culprit for his sin Or he shows mercy on culprit, in either case that person will be free from his sin. But if King don't gives suitable punishment
to that culprit then King himself has to suffer from that punishment (which was needed to give to the culprit). Following [Ramayana verse](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga18/kishkindha_18_frame.htm) saying the same thing. When Rama was teaching Vali about Dharma...

> राजभिः धृत दण्डाः च कृत्वा पापानि मानवाः |
>   निर्मलाः स्वर्गम् आयान्ति सन्तः सुकृतिनो यथा || ४-१८-३१
>
> maanavaaH = humans; paapaani kR^itvaa = sins, on making; raajabhiH dhR^ita daNDaaH ca = by kings, imposed, punishment, also; nirmalaaH sukR^itinaH santaH yathaa = unblemished - sinless, with good deeds, pious souled ones, as with; svargam aayaanti = to heaven, they come.
>
> When kings impose proper punishment on the humans who have sinned, they become sinless and enter heaven as with the pious souls with good deeds.' So says one verse of Manu.
>
> शसनात् वा अपि मोक्षात् वा स्तेनः पापात् प्रमुच्यते |
>   राजा तु अशासन् पापस्य तद् आप्नोति किल्बिषम् || ४-१८-३२
>
> stenaH = a thief; shasanaat vaa api mokshaat vaa = by punishment, either, even, by releasing - by clemency, or; paapaat pramucyate = from sin, will be released; a shaasan raajaa tu = un, punishing, king, but; paapasya tat kilbiSam aapnoti = sin's, that, blot, he derives.
>
> Either by punishment or by clemency a thief will be absolved from sin, but the king who does not impose proper punishment will derive the blot of that sin.' So says the other verse of Manu.

Answer (score 9):

**NO**.

As said in Rishabh's answer, once the King (or Government in today's time) punishes an evil-doer then he (the evil-doer) is free from the guilt.

> Manu Smriti 8.318. But men who have **committed crimes and have been
>   punished by the king, go to heaven, being pure like those who
>   performed meritorious deeds.**

If the King pardons the evil-doer, even then, it is considered that the evil-doer is freed from the guilt as said in the following verse. But in that case, it is the King who takes upon himself the guilt of the evil-doer.

> Manu Smriti 8.316. Whether **he be punished or pardoned, the thief is
>   freed from the (guilt of) theft;** but the king, if he punishes not,
>   takes upon himself the guilt of the thief.

Comment: Interesting. Corrupt judges are then, taking sins of sinners making them sinless.

Comment: @Rohit. Yes  and sometimes we also find pleas being made to reduce punishments for heinous criminals on grounds of "humanity" etc..In such cases too the judges (who approve such pleas) are similarly guilty.

Comment: @Rohit., Rickross, suppose if the judge isn't corrupt but due to law procedures, he/she reduces the punishment; In such case, the whole society collectively would suffer the punishment OR/AND the culprit would be punished in afterlife. Also imagine that a judge hands are bound by current law proceedings, they are helpless due to current system of law being practiced. If anyone of you get to see "Jolly LLB 1/2", judge says that mostly they know the culprit in very beginning Yet they can't punish due to law limitation. In current times of Democracy, Manu's interpretations would also changed :-).

Comment: @iammilind sins are always associated with an identity. In such cases, whoever is identified as an Indian will get sins.

Comment: @K.C.Polai Are you telling me something? Sorry i did not understand what you wanted to convey.

Comment: @K.C.Polai *if the judge isn't corrupt but due to law procedures, he/she reduces the punishment; In such case, the whole society collectively would suffer the punishment OR/AND the culprit would be punished in afterlife.* In such case whoever is identified as an Indian will get sin.